# Why can duplicate objective-C objects be declared in a loop, but not in sequence?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scope

I am just learning objective-C, and am wondering why the following code results in an error?

```
Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
```

In this case, the second line gives an error stating the "p" pointer has already been defined.

This makes sense to me; however, if it is true that a pointer cannot be re-defined, then why does the following code work?

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i+=1) {
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
}
```

When I enter this in XCode it does not give any errors, and it compiles and runs just fine. In this case, I'd expect the loop to simply re-define the "p" pointer, similar to having them be declared sequentially, but this is not the case.

Does anyone have an explanation for why this is?

Comment: Hot Licks....unhelpful!

Comment: Why the down votes on the question. It's rare that a new user posts a decent question these days. This behavior should be rewarded. This question is clear, it has relevant code. What else do you want?

Comment: Echoing @rmaddy: questions that demonstrate a "newbie" misunderstanding are not bad questions, as long as they're clearly stated. This is a well written question and shows some effort to understand the problem.

Comment: Someone who is "just learning Objective-C" should already know C or Java.  The above is not an Objective-C question, it's a general programming knowledge question.  If the OP does not know this he should go back and learn more before attempting Objective-C.  It is not a beginner's language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
```

In the first case, two `p` in the same local scope, they are all local variables, so they have the same priority. We can't have two variable with the same name and the same priority.

```
Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
{
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
}
```

The above case will be ok because the second `p` has higher priority in its local scope than the first `p`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i+=1) {
    Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
}
```

In the second case, all the `p` are in different local scopes.

Comment: FYI - The second example can cause a warning if you turn on the "Hidden Local Variables" warning.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, it is because in the case of the for-loop the variable `p` is local to the loop itself, so at the end of each iteration `p` and any other variables local only to the loop's scope is deallocated.

Comment: It's not an issue of the variables being deallocated. It's an issue of scope. It's only about variable scope, not object lifetime.

Comment: @rmaddy Correct, but I think that the object lifetime is tangential to scope and was worth mentioning.